# why am i getting this error in asp.net mvc C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Views/Random.cshtml

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4210.0

Comment: In asp.net MVC you view a page by going to the URL of an action method. You should never access a cshtml file directly.

Comment: That happens when you press F5 in Visual Studio from an opened cshtml file. In the project properties change the "start url" to be something fixed, such as `/`.